# Two Application in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How to code 2 application on codeigniter.

Example I have 2 application : Facebook and twitter use Codeigniter.
On home I can choose go to facebook or twitter.

Comment: do you mean each project has it's own codeigniter folder or your planning to integrate the 2 code in one codeigniter framework.

Comment: you can create two controller. Example Facebook_controller and Twitter_controller then from home you can redirect to them.

Comment: @mrdragon yes true. How i build page for choose two controller ? I mean where folder i build code for page choose two controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a easy demo.
In controllers folder:
You create a controller: Home_controller

```
class Home_controller extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        echo "<a href ='index.php/facebook_controller'>Facebook</a><br>";
        echo "<a href ='index.php/twitter_controller'>Twitter</a>";
    }
}
```

Then you create facebook_controller and twitter_controller like this:
Facebook_controller:

```
class Facebook_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo "This is facebook_controller";
    }
}
```

Twitter_controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Twitter_controller extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        echo "This is twitter_controller";
    }
}
```

Hope this help.